# Rational points on quotient of Fermat curve by symmetric group

Tags: nt.number-theory

One may take a quotient of the Fermat curve $x^n+y^n+z^n=0$ by the symmetric group $S_3$ permuting the coordinates. This should be a curve defined by a polynomial $p_n(e_1,e_2,e_3)=0$, where $e_1=x+y+z,e_2=xy+xz+yz,e_3=xyz$. Using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_power_sums_in_terms_of_elementary_symmetric_polynomials), we see that $p_{n+1}=e_1p_n-e_2p_{n-1}+e_3p_{n-2}$, with $p_1=e_1,p_2=e_1^2-2e_2, p_3=e_1^3-3e_1e_2+3e_3$. Projectivizing, these curve will lie in $\mathbb{CP}^3$, or you can think of them as lying in a weighted projective space.

As $n\to \infty$, the genus of this quotient goes to $\infty$, so the [Mordell Conjecture/Falting's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faltings%27s_theorem) implies that there are finitely many rational points on the curve $p_n=0$. I'm curious if it's known whether there are no non-trivial rational solutions for large enough $n$ (so this would be a strengthening of Fermat's last theorem if true)?

Comment: If instead of the whole $S_3$ you look at the cyclic subgroups of order $2$, then this is a special case of looking at quadratic points on the Fermat curve, which has a large literature (particularly Siksek et al.). The question is not fully resolved but it may be possible to restrict which quadratic fields occur here.

Comment: OTOH. If $(x,y,z)=(1,\omega,\omega^2), \omega^3=1, \omega\ne 1$, the symmetric functions are rational and the point is on the Fermat curve if $3\nmid n$.

Comment: In the case $N=7$, it is a theorem of Genocchi (1864) that if $x,y,z$ are the solutions of a cubic polynomial with rational coefficients, and $x^7+y^7+z^7=0$, then either $xyz=0$ or $x^3=y^3=z^3$ (I learned this from Elkies's article on the Klein quartic).

Comment: You can by homogeneity set $e_1=1$, which for low $N$ makes the degree manageable. If $N=3$ or $5$ there are trivially infinitely many solutions (you can express $e_3$ as a rational function of $e_1$ and $e_2$).


For $N=7$ after a little effort the problem reduces (amazingly) to an elliptic curve of rank 0. You can check this on LMFDB or even by hand via a 2-descent. The torsion points correspond to nonsensical cubics.


I'm going to have a go at higher degrees, starting with $N=9$. I'll let you know how that goes. Unfortunately a general proof is (currently) above my paygrade.

Comment: Yeah even $N=9$ is no longer a genus 1 curve, so the number of solutions will be finite. I'll ask about that curve in a different question.